# derivatives and distribution of a 3-dimensional copula in R

Tags: distributions, density-function, copula, derivative

I am looking for a way to calculate in the R software, the distribution, the density and the derivatives (of order 1, 2) partial of a Gaussian copula of dimension 3.
Indeed, I have three variables (u1, u2 and u3 ) with real values in [0,1], the three correlations r2,r2 and r3 from a kinship matrix. I am looking for the distribution of the copula C(u1, u2, u3), its density and its partial derivatives d/d_u1{ C(u1, u2, u3)}, d^2/d_u1, d_u2{ C(u1, u2, u3)}.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide the exprssion of the copula? Write it directly in your post.

Comment: I don't know how to write in latex on this site but you can find the definition of a Gaussian copula on page 5 of the following document http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/QRM/Copulas.pdf. However, it is the R functions that could help me to calculate the different aforementioned quantities that interest me. I was using Vinecopula packages for bivariate cases. Thanks

Comment: "it is the R functions ... that interest me" suggests that your question might potentially be off topic. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic in the section that starts with the highlighted word **Programming**.

Comment: I do not think so. I'm just trying to guide the attempts to answer so you don't waste your time on problems for which I already have a solution. Thanks